# unable to use optional int "possibleNumber" in optional binding

Tags: xcode, swift, option-type, optional-binding

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn the concept of optional binding. I have came up with the following code:

```
let possibleNumber = Int("123")
possibleNumber.dynamicType
if let actualNumber = Int(possibleNumber){
    print("\(possibleNumber) has an integer value of \(actualNumber)")
} else {
    print("\(possibleNumber) could not be converted to an int")
}
```

Xcode playground output error message:

```
value of optional type "int?" not unwrapped, did you mean to use "!" or "?"
```

However, when I added the "!" to  `if let actualNumber = Int(possibleNumber!){`

```
let possibleNumber = Int("123")
possibleNumber.dynamicType
if let actualNumber = Int(possibleNumber!){
    print("\(possibleNumber) has an integer value of \(actualNumber)")
} else {
    print("\(possibleNumber) could not be converted to an int")
}
```

Xcode display another error message:

```
initialiser for conditional binding must have Optional type, not int
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of

```
let possibleNumber = Int("123")
```

is an optional Int - `Int?`

Then you're trying to create another `Int` with

```
Int(possibleNumber)
```

which does not work because the initializer expects a non-optional type.
The error message is related to the initializer rather than to the optional binding.

Try this to get the same error message.

```
let possibleNumber = Int("123")
let x = Int(possibleNumber)
```

---

In your second example when you initialize an `Int` with an implicit unwrapped `Int!` argument you get a non-optional `Int` and the compiler complains about the missing optional.

Comment: Am I correct in saying, for the second example, the statement,  if let actualNumber = Int(possibleNumber), actualNumber is expected to be of a optional type, however, Int(possibleNumber!) is equal to a non-optional int type, and this is the reason why XCode is complaining?

Answer (score 1):

In the `if let` construct

```
if let actualNumber = Int(possibleNumber!){
    print("\(possibleNumber) has an integer value of \(actualNumber)")
}
```

you don't need to use the `Int` initializer. You simply need to write

```
if let actualNumber = possibleNumber {
    print("\(possibleNumber) has an integer value of \(actualNumber)")
}
```

Now Swift will try to unwrap `possibleNumber`. If the operation does succeed the unwrapped value is put inside `actualNumber` and the `THEN` block executed.